# "Opening and creating websites on iis requires running visual studio under an administrator account"

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

I'm seeing this error in a pop-up window when attempting to run/debug my web project from Visual Studio

> The following error occurred when trying to configure IIS Express. Opening and creating websites on iis requires running visual studio under an administrator account

This happened completely out of the blue. One second I was working as normal, regularly going in and out of debug in my browser, then this error pops up. It happens when attempting to run *any* web project, and it doesn't matter if it's in debug, release mode or what.

Stuff I've tried:

- Run Visual Studio as Administrator
- Uninstall/Reinstall IIS Express (via "Turn Windows Features On or Off" in Control Panel)
- Update Visual Studio
- Delete project's `.vs` folder

But still the error persists.

Is there anything else I can reinstall, update or otherwise check?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by going through a day of hell, and to be honest the 'solution' was very brute force...

#### TL;DR: Fully deleting and reinstalling Visual Studio seemed to do the trick.

Since the usual methods weren't working, I tried a full reinstall of Visual Studio. That didn't help. I then tried a System Restore. That made everything far worse, with my project showing about 500 error messages!

I then undid the System Restore, completely deleted all traces of Visual Studio from my computer, reinstalled everything, then tried VS2019 preview edition, tried 2017 edition again, uninstalled and reinstalled NetCore 2.0, 2.1, 2.2... all just to get around the minefield of error messages I'd created for myself.

In the end I just needed to do a full NuGet clear and restore then run `dotnet restore --force` in the NPM console, after which all those error messages were gone. As well as this, the original IIS Administrator error was gone too, presumably fixed via the original reinstall of Visual Studio.

Lost a whole day to this quagmire.

Answer (score 0):

Downloading & Installing IIS Express from Microsoft worked for me. No need to update VS or remove/re-add the project.